# 'This computer does not have enough space for temporary files...' error 0x80070103

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install windows server 2008 r2 a computer with multiple drives. My c drive has 3gb space, and I have 2 other hardrives with more than 100gb space.

The error is telling me I need about 1gb of space to install windows server.

I have looked at trying to set the partition as active through the computer management console, but an asterisk message saying 'only mark partition as active if it has a functioning operating system..." All of the other drives have the partition as active. I am worried the computer will stop working if I set the partition as active. Any way to test and see if it has an operating system?

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Setting a partition as "active" means it is the boot partition when that drive is booted.  It does not mean anything else.

You can test for a bootable partition by setting it active and trying to boot it.  If it works, then it is is bootable.

However, the "active status" of a partition has nothing to do with the problem of disk space.  Whether a partition is bootable or not does not change whether windows is mounting the partition and making it available for use.

Usually a windows install process, especially when it is from a Microsoft product, requesting a particular amount of space means on the system partition.  Most non-Microsoft products install just fine and work on other partitions.

Your options for installing windows server are to make another disk the primary disk (by swapping the drives around on the cables) and install the OS onto it, making use of available space—though be aware the *default* installation option is to blow away the entire partition before installing, or to use the current primary disk by deleting enough stuff to satisfy the installation program.