# How to resolve error 0x80070103 when updating Nvidia drivers in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

I updated my Windows 8 to 10 today. After updating my drivers, I got this error:

> NVIDIA driver update for NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti - Error 0x80070103

This is [the thread](http://setiathome.berkeley.edu/forum_thread.php?id=77121&sort_style=&start=480) I found about it, no answers yet. Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Have you seen http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/windows-update-error-0x80070103 ? - this error normally indicates "you might be trying to install a driver that's already installed, or a driver that might be less compatible than one you already have installed on your PC"

Comment: I didn't do anything manually, I literally just installed Windows and click "Update my drivers".

Comment: @Ramhound I never understand why that is. Why can't I use the default, streamlined update mechanism? Anyway I think they changed something in Win10 to make updates more streamlined, at least for NVidia.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have version 10.18.13.5362 released on 23/07/2015.

Comment: I told you, via Windows Update...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['This computer does not have enough space for temporary files...' error 0x80070103](https://superuser.com/questions/472518/this-computer-does-not-have-enough-space-for-temporary-files-error-0x800701)